# zend framework 2 crontab issue

Tags: php, zend-framework2, cron, cpanel

I am trying to set up a cronjob in zendframework 2, I have added a console route and everything. The OS is CentOS with cpanel.

The command is:

```
php /home/ACCOUNT/public_html/cron.php cron
```

and is added as root in crontab via terminal.

The issue:

**When the crontab runs(every minute: */1 * * * *) the output is:**

> Status: 302 Found
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.32
>   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=XXXXXXXXXXXX; path=/
>   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Location: /user/login
>   Content-type: text/html

**BUT**, when i run the command directly from console or terminal(as root) the command is executed perfectly.

Should there be any different?

**EDIT:**
Got it working with:

/usr/local/bin/php instead of just php

by using linux command: "which php" to find my php path. Note: this can be different.

Comment: Looks like you are getting redirected because of an authentication or permission check. Though I am unable to answer the difference between terminal and cron executions, maybe checking why it is trying to authenticate will resolve it.